# How to get Folder auto complete in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, model-view-controller, intellisense

My folder auto complete isn't working anymore.

Before I can type src="~/" and it will give me a list of suggestions.

Now it doesn't

[image]

What should I do to resolve this?

Comment: Only the `src=""` stop working or all intellisense stop working?

Comment: only folder suggestions stopped working, everything else seems fine. Things such as href="" doesn't suggest folders to me anymore

Comment: Do you mean the intellisense works fine before and not work now in the same file? If so, you can try to create a new file with the same type under the same folder or project, then try it again. Or think about if you made any changes to this project or install any extensions in VS.

Comment: Ahh yes I created a new project and typing src="" seems to be giving me folder suggestions again. However, the old project still doesn't, why is that??

Comment: Have you made any changes for your old project? You can try to clean up or reload the old project after restart VS, and check this issue again. Or create a new Blank solution and copy your projects into this new solution to see if the old solution is corrupted or broken.

Comment: Thank you heaps for helping me Sara, and yes for my old project I installed AngularJs using Nutget package. Could that be a reason it caused the issue?

Comment: @JohnLington, you can try to uninstall the AngularJs to test this issue.

Comment: @JohnLington, after uninstall the AngularJs, this issue is persists or not?

Comment: @Sara-MSFT, sorry for not getting back, but yes after uninstalling AngularJs the issue has still persisted. I think the project might have being corrupted somehow so I copied to a new project and it's working again. Thanks for the assistance !

Comment: @JohnLington, so glad to hear that your issue is solved and could you please add a reply with your workaround and mark it as answer? That will help others who meet the same issue to troubleshot with this useful information:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarising Sara-MSFT and I's conversation, it comes down to the following:

1) The most Important step is knowing that the src="" folder suggestion only works on .cshtml extension and not .html so make sure the file is in .cshtml ONLY and opened in Visual Studio.

2) Make sure to refresh intellisense and fix any problems associated with intellisense.

And if those don't work

3) Make sure to delete any previous Nut Get extensions to see if that fixes the problem.

4) And if none of those works then the file may have being corrupted.